# Combine two datasets with each their own X and Y axes in same plot in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

We have two datasets that each consist of an X and an Y axis. The two X and the two Y axes have the same scaling (millimeters) but the values of course differ. So for the X values in dataset 1 there are no corresponding values in dataset 2.

If we just put the plots into one plot with dual X and dual Y axes, the two datasets are somehow combined into four different plots, one for each combination of the X and Y axes. Like we want the plot for X1/Y1 and for X2/Y2. What we're also seeing are plots X1/Y2 and X2/Y1 which do not make any sense at all.

How do we correctly combine the two datasets into a single plot where they only *share* the same X and Y axes but do not *mix* like that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to combine and reshape your data to have 3 columns;X, Y, Type - where Type distinguishes between the data sets, could be actual vs predicted for example. Then just put x (as a continuous dimension) on columns, y on rows and type on color or detail.

You can reshape the data like this using the UNION feature when defining your data source